# Setting Java 1.6 as the default on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: java, macos, java-6

How can I set Java 1.6 to be the default for my MacBook Pro Intel Core 2 Duo with OS X 10.5.8? I have installed the latest software update, and dragged the Java SE 6 64-bit choice to the top in the "Java Preferences" application (and even rebooted), but still, on the command line, java -version responds with:

```
java version "1.5.0_24"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_24-b02-357-9M3165)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_24-149, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Eyvind change your environmental variable to point to new version of java. JAVA_HOME

Comment: Thanks - I'm a little embarrassed to even be asking this, but where exactly is the other version? I.e., where should I point JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @Eyvind you need to download it from java website first then install it and when you do change the location of JAVA_HOMe to the new location you just installed

Comment: @Eyvind: Can you put Java 6 at the top of the list and deselect all the other JVM's and try again. You might want to open a new terminal after you make the changes?

Comment: @c0mrade - on Mac it is installed automagically, so I have no idea where the OS has put it.

Comment: @Snehal - that didn't work, unfortunately. java -version still answers 1.5.0_24.

Comment: I don't really know what automagically means but there must be way to point to the right location, I'm not using mac so I can't tell you

Answer (score 2):

There are symbolic link in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework

They point to a specific version in the Versions sub folder.

I have had these links breaking on occasion.

AFAICT there is a Current link which points to the Current JRE and a CurrentJDK.

Verify if all the links are pointing somewhere logical. Aparently the Java configlet does something but the chains of links gets broken somewhere else.

Sorry I wish I could be of more help, but it is all rather mysterious to me. I have always been able to  fix it, but it was not pretty.

Comment: Thank you, that helped my understanding a great deal!

Answer (score 2):

For temporal changes:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/
```